# Bootstrap 4.1.3 NavBar link doesnt work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, helper

I started doing website now and I've known the bootstrap a little while ago. I'm here because I have a problem with navbar link's.
On the homepage the links work perfectly but on the following pages does not work. the same menu.

If anyone can help, I really appreciate it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--Index-->
<html lang="pt">
  <head>

    <title>Urbisouto - A tua imobiliaria</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
    
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.png">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,900|Oswald:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/icomoon/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aos.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">
  
  <div class="site-wrap">

    <div class="site-mobile-menu site-navbar-target">
      <div class="site-mobile-menu-header">
        <div class="site-mobile-menu-close mt-3">
          <span class="icon-close2 js-menu-toggle"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="site-mobile-menu-body"></div>
    </div>
   
    
    <header class="site-navbar py-4 js-sticky-header site-navbar-target" role="banner">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          
          <div class="col-6 col-xl-2">
            <h1 class="mb-0 site-logo m-0 p-0"><a href="index.html" class="mb-0">logo</a></h1>
          </div> 

          <div class="col-12 col-md-10 d-none d-xl-block">
            <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">

              <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                <li><a href="#home-section" class="nav-link">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#properties-section" class="nav-link">Imoveis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#agents-section" class="nav-link">Agentes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about-section" class="nav-link">Sobre nós</a></li>
               <!-- <li><a href="#news-section" class="nav-link">News</a></li>  -->
                <li><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link">Contactos</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>


          <div class="col-6 d-inline-block d-xl-none ml-md-0 py-3"><a href="#" class="site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle text-white float-right"><span class="icon-menu h3"></span></a></div>

        </div>
      </div>
      
    </header>

    
    <div class="site-block-wrap">
    <div class="owl-carousel with-dots">
      <div class="site-blocks-cover overlay overlay-2" style="background-image: url(images/intro_1.jpg);" data-aos="fade" id="home-section">


        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-lg-5 text-center">
              <h1 class="text-shadow">123</h1>
              <p class="mb-5 text-shadow">321</p>
              <p>  <a href="#properties-section" class="btn btn-primary px-5 py-3" class="smoothscroll arrow-down" class="nav-link" >go</a></p>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        
      </div>  
  
      <div class="site-blocks-cover overlay overlay-2" style="background-image: url(images/intro_2.jpg);" data-aos="fade" id="home-section">
  
  
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-lg-5 text-center">
              <h1 class="text-shadow">123</h1>
              <p class="mb-5 text-shadow">321</p>
              <p><a href="#properties-section" class="btn btn-primary px-5 py-3" class="smoothscroll arrow-down" class="nav-link">go</a></p>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        
      </div>  
    </div>   
    
  </div>      


  <div class="site-section" id="properties-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row large-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5 mb-lg-5 ">
            <div class="ftco-media-1">
              <div class="ftco-media-1-inner">
                <a href="vieira.html" class="d-inline-block mb-4"><img src="images/vieira/homepage.jpg" alt="#" class="img-fluid"></a>
                <div class="ftco-media-details">
                  <h3>Vieira do Minho</h3>
                  <p>Braga</p>
                  <strong>€1.150.000,00</strong>
                </div>
  
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>          
   
    <footer class="site-footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5">
                 <h2 class="footer-heading mb-4">Sobre nós</h2>
                <p>Fundada em 1998, a Urbisouto caracteriza-se por ser uma agência imobiliária, com uma grande experiência no mercado, empenhada em satisfazer a necessidade de quem nos procura.
                Fazemos pesquisas de mercado para garantir o melhor preço.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">
                <h2 class="footer-heading mb-4">Quick Links</h2>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href="index.html#contact-section">Sobre nós</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.html#services-section">Serviços</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.html#testimonials-section">Testemunhos de clientes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.html#contact-section">Contactos</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        <!--  <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="mb-4">
              <h2 class="footer-heading mb-4">Subscribe Newsletter</h2>
            <form action="#" method="post" class="footer-subscribe">
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border-secondary text-white bg-transparent" placeholder="Enter Email" aria-label="Enter Email" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary text-black" type="button" id="button-addon2">Send</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>  
            </div> -->
            
           <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">
              <h2 class="footer-heading mb-4">Segue-nos</h2>
                  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Urbisouto-450056462169603" target="_blank" ><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a>
                  <!-- <a href="www.twitter.com"><span class="icon-twitter"></span></a>
                  <a href="www.linkdin.com"><span class="icon-linkedin"></span></a>
                  <a href="www.instagram.com"><span class="icon-instagram"></span></a>  -->
                  <a href=""></a>
                  <a href=""></a>
                  <a href=""></a>
            </div> 


          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row pt-5 mt-5 text-center">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="border-top pt-5">
            <p class="copyright"><small>&copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> Urbisouto - Empreendimentos Copyrigth.  Design by Albino Teixeira</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </div>

  <a href="#top" class="gototop"><span class="icon-angle-double-up"></span></a> 

  <script tpye="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>

  
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I remember than on desktop it works well, just in mobile dont work on second page

Comment: Here is the link of all the code: https://files.fm/u/f54c2ste

Comment: if you share minimal working snippet which reproduces the issue, it will be easier to help

Comment: Hello sir, the website is online,www.urbisouto.pt. u can check it if u want, the problem is only in mobile mode and on 2º page's

Comment: On mobile = safari? Or what browser do you mean?

Comment: Yes sir, i try on iOS (Iphone) with safari and on my Samsung Galaxy s7 Edge with google Chrome. If ur are able to teste visite the website and click in 1 house and then try the nabber, www.urbisouto.pt